# Android Realm - Unable to open realm at path : read_only file system

Tags: android, database, exception, permissions, realm

We're using Realm database in our app for a while now, but recently we noticed some strange logs coming from some of our users, about an incapacity of Realm to open an instance, due to a lack of permission on the realm.lock

This issue appears quite randomly, meaning that the issue is triggered in many differents places in our code, but not systematically at all. It happened even  after an instance has been succesfully opened (and close) few times before.
We haven't been able to reproduce it. 
It happens on Samsung SMT-580 on Android 7.0 .
In our app we're using Realm 4.2.0

As I said it happens when we're trying to open a Realm instance, for example :

```java
    Realm realmInstance = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    try {
         RealmResults<Object> results = realmInstance.where(...).findAll();
               ...
    }
    finally {
         realmInstance.close();
    }
```

The error we're receiving is this one :

> "Unable to open a realm at path
>   '/data/data/com.xxx/files/default.realm.lock'. Please use a path where
>   your app has read-write permissions.
>   (open("/data/data/com.xxx/files/default.realm.lock") failed: Read-only
>   file system) (/data/data/com.xxx/files/default.realm.lock) in
>   /home/cc/repo/realm/release/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsSharedRealm.cpp
>   line 101"

We've no idea why this is happening, and why this problem seems to has appeared recently (we did not make any changes in this parts)

We've find this issue on Realm Github : 
https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5715
but not sure if this is really related

Comment: This is different than that issue, but I do not know what to do with this one (just like that one) either.